# My button's background-color us not working in IE

Tags: html, css

I have a button with a background-color that is not working in IE 11.

This one is what it should like look (Firefox)
[image: Firefox - working]

And in IE:

[image: IE11 - not working]

```css
.loginButton {
    width: 100% !important;
    background-color: rgb(0, 148, 146, 0.8) !important;
    border: 0px !important;
    font-size: 2em !important;
    letter-spacing: 1px !important;
    border: 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 5% !important;
    filter: none !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

.loginButton span {
    cursor: pointer !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    position: relative !important;
    transition: 2.5s !important;
}

.loginButton span:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome !important;
    content: "\f101" !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    right: -20px !important;
    transition: 0.5s !important;
}

.loginButton:hover {
    border-color: rgb(31, 153, 214) !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    transition: all 0.9s ease !important;
}

.loginButton:hover span {
    padding-right: 30px !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    letter-spacing: 3px !important;
    transition: all 0.9s ease !important;
}

.loginButton:hover span:after {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    right: 0px !important;
}

.loginButton:after {
    width: 100% !important;
    background-color: white !important;
    border: 0px !important;
    font-size: 2em !important;
}
```

```html
<b:commandButton styleClass="loginButton" tooltip-position="right" tooltip="Melde dich beim IUBH-Ticketssystem an">
    <span>Anmelden </span>
</b:commandButton>
```

Comment: `rgb()` takes three numbers, but you've supplied 4. Perhaps you meant `rgba(0, 148, 146, 0.8)`? I'd assume some browsers could be "smart enough" to fix this for you by dropping the fourth value, whereas IE sees it as a mistake and ignores the property entirely.

Comment: Why `!important` on everything? When everything is `!important`, nothing is.

Comment: As a follow-up to my previous comment, I created a [quick JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qbbmx4z/) to satiate my own curiosity (the background-color "working in Firefox" despite the syntax errors just seemed... *wrong* to me). In all three major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge) the invalid `rgb` declaration is entirely ignored, so I'm not exactly sure how you're getting the correct background color in Firefox, unless that screenshot was taken while triggering the `:hover` (which you've correctly only supplied *3* values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand why your background-color working on Firefox. 
In my demo, i got error invalid value

```
background-color: rgb(0, 148, 146, 0.8) !important;
```

should be changed to

```
background-color: rgba(0, 148, 146, 0.8) !important;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5qbbmx4z/6/

And You should NOT use `!important` as much as possible.